# Dell Latitude 5430 freezing unpredictably, sometimes returns control. DRM errors?

Tags: dell, freeze

My Linux environment freezes from time to time. The laptop is a Dell Latitude 5430, and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and using Xorg instead of Wayland (seems to work better for Discord screen sharing). I've had the laptop since around 2023-11-10. If I remember right, it was refurbished.

Here's the information on the events I have:

While playing gzdoom and screen sharing it through Discord, I would occasionally get 10 second freezes. I am unsure whether I was audible or not at those times. I could not hear the person I was talking to.

Now my computer is freezing on its own, and more permanently. A YouTube video playing in the background for one freeze continued to be audible.
Sometimes I get to move my mouse during these freezes, sometimes not.
Some freezes occur after an hour or so, one or two have appeared shortly after logging in.

I used pcmemtest for 3 hours and 23 minutes and it found no errors.
Next, I tried leaving system monitor and htop open on my laptop's internal display.
It froze after a while and displayed a time about 20 minutes out of date when I came back to it. I couldn't see anything weird, but here are photos of the windows anyway (which were of course frozen):

[image: System Monitor photo]
[image: htop photo]

I then did ctrl-alt-f4 to jump to tty4 and it was stuck on a non-blinking underscore (on the laptop screen and external monitor) for a while, then showed a bunch of errors all at once. Here are the errors, all labelled drm:

[image: tty4 errors]

Seeing that the errors mention HDMI, I unplugged the HDMI cable to my external monitor (though the original freezes were done with no external monitor)-- no progress-- and put it back in. The laptop then seemed to go under heavy load (high fan with heat coming from the vents). I then did REISUB (which requires me to hold ctrl and alt for some reason, unlike what most others need to use from what I've read).

While typing this question, it froze again. I then went to tty4 and after a while was given control. I returned to the X tty and could continue writing my question. So it seems the freezes are sometimes not permanent.

I hope all this info is useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour in an HP laptop. In particular, I get the exact same drm errors.

Comment: I upgraded my kernel, no freezes since.